# Why is a state created automatically? (redux)

Tags: react-redux

Redux automatically adds an entry called state. Practice creating counter function. However, the state item that I did not set is automatically added so that it does not appear in the desired direction when dispacth is executed.
I guess it's caused by combineReducers, but I don't know exactly.
Clearly, I didn't make State in counter.

[image]

[image]

```
//action name

const INCRE = 'counter/INCRE';
const DECRE = 'counter/DECRE';


export const incre = () => ({type: INCRE});
export const decre = () => ({type: DECRE});

//default 
const initState = {
    number: 0
}; 

//reducer 
function counter(state = initState, action) {
    console.log("frist value");
    console.log(state.number);
    console.log(initState);

    if(action.type === INCRE){
            console.log("add");
            console.log(state.number)
            return {number: state.number +1 }
    }else if (action.type === DECRE) {
        console.log("minus");
            return {number: state.number -1 }
    } 
    else {
        return{state};
    };

};

export default counter;
```

```
// C is containers & Counter is name
import React from 'react';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {incre, decre} from '../modules/counter';

const CCounter = ({number, incre, decre}) => {
    return (
    <Counter number={number} onIncre={incre} onDecre={decre}/>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    number: state.counter.number
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    incre: () => {
        dispatch(incre());
    },
    decre: () => {
        dispatch(decre());
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CCounter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//reducer
//...
    else {
        return{state};
    };
```

The above line in your reducer is likely the problem because what it can return is what you're seeing:

```
{
    state: {
      number: 0,
    }
}
```

You probably wanted to simply return the state.

```
    else {
        return state;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks to advice! i fixed like that! else return state.number